# Heroku requires OpenJDK version 6 for Playframework - Is there any OpenJDK 6 for Mac os Lion?

Tags: macos, heroku, playframework, osx-lion, java

I just started developing an application with Playframework (Java) and I thought it is good idea testing it with Heroku which supports Playframework.

In prerequisites for Playframework on Heroku a requirement is that the application must run on the OpenJDK version 6. I don't find any OpenJDK version 6 for Mac. Not a stable one anyway, just in dev.

Do you know how to go around this?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenJDK6 can be installed on OS X using MacPorts:

```
$ port search openjdk6
openjdk6 @b20 (java)
    Oracle's Java 6 virtual machine release under the GPL v2

openjdk6_bootstrap @b16-r1 (java)
    A binary build of OpenJDK6 to be used for bootstrapping the OpenJDK6 port.

Found 2 ports.
$ sudo port install openjdk6
```